# Can't install Ubuntu on Dell G3 15 and Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, dell, format, 19.04

We bought two new computers : Dell G3 15 and Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming.
Both of them come with Ubuntu 16.04 pre-installed.

- We tried to reinstall the latest Ubuntu version 19.04 => The machine freeze during the installation.
- We tried Ubuntu 18.04 LTS => The machine freeze during the installation also.
- We tried Ubuntu 16.04 LTS => We can install it but then the computer freeze during the OS loading.
- We tried even to install Linux Mint 19.1, Fedora and other Linux system => For some of them We can install the OS but it show a black screen after the login.

It looks like the system is not compatible with Linux at all and responds with different behaviors for each version.

Is there any one who found a solution for this ?
I tried some hack like [this one](https://erdnaxe.github.io/dell-g3-17-ubuntu/) but it does not work in my case.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Systems sold with a factory installed Ubuntu are definitely compatible with Ubuntu :) The problem is the Nvidia graphics. To install you need to boot in UEFI mode and add `nomodeset` as additional parameter (also in the first boot), then install the recommended Nvidia drivers. I'm sure you would find his information just by googling.

Comment: @Zied HF: Did this solve your problem? I'm thinking of getting a G3 15 myself.

Comment: @user32849 There a lot of problems with this version even if it works for sometimes. Dell support said it's running only on version 16.04 LTS. We installed Windows on that machine.

Answer (score 2):

iyadh is right

But be cautious with the "nouveau" kernel module since it causes various problems during the system boot.
In tested Ubuntu releases since 16.04 - 16.04.6 up to 19.04.2 and only 16.04 didn't have any problems during the boot.

But it has kinda old kernel version 4.05 which does not have required wifi driver and firmware.

So you need to choose any distribution with the kernel version higher than 4.14 to support the wifi card.

The installing process of the new OS must be preceding by switching off the 'nouveau' kernel module in grub boot menu by adding nouveau.modeset=0 parameter into the grub params like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite spash nouveau.modeset=0"
```

It will prevent opensource nvidia 'nouveau' driver from loading and the system will boot without freezing.

Than during the first boot enter the recovery mode as root and disable nouveau module from loading

```
echo blacklist nouveau /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf

update-initramfs -u

reboot
```

That's it. Now the system must be able to boot safely without freezing.

And one more thing about proprietary nvidia-driver I'd not recommend install it prior the nvidia-detect application gives the sensible output. When I tried to run it it didn't suggest any drivers and just hang.

Comment: correction the blocking line must be
```echo blacklist nouveau >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf```

Answer (score 0):

Try https://system76.com/pop with NVIDIA ISO.

Ubuntu 19.04 based ISO with gnome feel. Works out of the box for Dell G3 15 for me.

Answer (score 0):

try to click **e** when the screen show "try ubuntu,install ubuntu..etc" then add "nouveau.modeset=0" to the linux line, you should do this when you install ubuntu and also when you will open it for the first time

Answer (score 0):

It happens with most users while installing an Ubuntu version less than 19.*. I was also having a freezing screen problem with several errors on my Dell G3 15 3579 i5 laptop, but installing Ubuntu 19.*, helped me resolve this issue.

Change your boot sequence to USB or DVD in boot setup and just proceed to install. It will work perfectly.